# How to download scrapy images in to a dynamic folder?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am able to download images through scrapy in to the "Full" folder but I need to make the name of the destination folder dynamic, like `full/session_id`, every time scrapy runs.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You should tell us, how you are currently downloading the images (some code). With a middleware? From your spider? ...?

Comment: ya from my spider only i have  enabled the pipeline and add download folder path as given in docs

Comment: Didn't know scrapy has included pipelines. [Link for others](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not worked with the `ImagesPipeline` yet, but [following the documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20141208034733/http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html#scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline), I'd override `item_completed(results, items, info)`.

The original definition is:

```
def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
    if self.IMAGES_RESULT_FIELD in item.fields:
        item[self.IMAGES_RESULT_FIELD] = [x for ok, x in results if ok]
    return item
```

This should give you the result sets of the downloaded images including the path (seems there can be many images on one item).

If you now change this method in a subclass to move all files before setting the path, it should work as you want. You could set the target folder on your item in something like `item['session_path']`. You'd have to set this setting on each item, before returning/yielding your items from the spider.

The subclass with overriden method could then look like this:

```
import os, os.path
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline

class SessionImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        # iterate over the local file paths of all downloaded images
        for result in [x for ok, x in results if ok]:
            path = result['path']
            # here we create the session-path where the files should be in the end
            # you'll have to change this path creation depending on your needs
            target_path = os.path.join((item['session_path'], os.basename(path)))

            # try to move the file and raise exception if not possible
            if not os.rename(path, target_path):
                raise ImageException("Could not move image to target folder")

            # here we'll write out the result with the new path,
            # if there is a result field on the item (just like the original code does)
            if self.IMAGES_RESULT_FIELD in item.fields:
                result['path'] = target_path
                item[self.IMAGES_RESULT_FIELD].append(result)

        return item
```

Even nicer would be to set the desired session path not in the `item`, but in the configuration during your scrapy run. For this, you would have to find out how to set config while the application is running and you'd have to override the constructor, I think.

Comment: hey your logic seems to be promising but where actually i have to put this ? in my class where i am scraping all data or in image pipeline class and also one thing how can use a variable from my class to this subclass Is there any way to do so? any help would be appricated

Comment: My code is a custom pipeline, so it goes to `pipelines.py`. From your own spider you'll have to set the `item['session_path']` to whatever you want and then `yield item` (as usual).

Comment: there should be some way to set desired folder(dynamically) in `def file_path`

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007995/how-to-download-scrapy-images-in-a-dyanmic-folder-based-on)

```
class StoreImgPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        image_guid = hashlib.sha1(to_bytes(request.url)).hexdigest()
        return 'realty-sc/%s/%s/%s/%s.jpg' % (YEAR, image_guid[:2], image_guid[2:4], image_guid)
```

Comment: don't forget to correct the settings file
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'webparser.pipelines.StoreImgPipeline': 1,
    # 'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1

}