# How to change the directory where images are saved, scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping images from a webpage.
I've several list of images:

```
list_1,list_2,list_3
```

each one of those list corresponds to a different category, so far all images are saved in the same directory, the one which is specified in the settings file

```
IMAGES_STORE = '/home/user/Desktop/folder1/folder2'
```

I want to save the images from each list in a different forder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386509/how-to-download-scrapy-images-in-a-dyanmic-folder) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007995/how-to-download-scrapy-images-in-a-dyanmic-folder-based-on).

Basically override the item_completed method and include your logic of where you want to save the images based on which list they come from.

```
def item_completed(self, results, item, info):

    for result in [x for ok, x in results if ok]:
        path = result['path']
        slug = slugify(item['designer'])


        settings = get_project_settings()
        storage = settings.get('IMAGES_STORE')

        target_path = os.path.join(storage, slug, os.path.basename(path))
        path = os.path.join(storage, path)

        # If path doesn't exist, it will be created
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(storage, slug)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(storage, slug))

        if not os.rename(path, target_path):
            raise DropItem("Could not move image to target folder")

    if self.IMAGES_RESULT_FIELD in item.fields:
        item[self.IMAGES_RESULT_FIELD] = [x for ok, x in results if ok]
    return item
```