# Scrapy - change settings of spider during run

Tags: scrapy, python-3.5

Is it possible to change settings of spider during the spider run? I tried to chenge it but I recieved error e.g.:

```
In [4]: settings.set('SPIDER_MODULES', ['a'])
TypeError: Trying to modify an immutable Settings object

In [5]: settings.update('SPIDER_MODULES', ['a'])
TypeError: Trying to modify an immutable Settings object
```

Comment: What is the use case here? What setting you want to change and why?

Comment: I would like to download pictures but not in one directory. So i have hash of picture e.g. 123456abcd. So I would like to save it under /1234/567. So I would like to change save directory for each file before it is downloaded.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386509/how-to-download-scrapy-images-in-to-a-dynamic-folder